# Preventing users to enter email in the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I've been using [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate my textarea doesn't contain email addresses.

I have a custom validator defined :

```
email = function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("email", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || !(value.match(/((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)*(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?/i));
    }, emailValidationFailedMessage);
  }
```

And it worked well. However if users put any of these :

(@)
[@]
{@}
|@|

instead of @, the email custom validator will not figure this. How can I edit this regex to add support for those as well?

Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your expression and replace @ with

```
(\[@\]|@|\{@\}|\(@\)|\|@\|\(@\))
```

or

```
([\[\{\|\(]?@[\]\}\|\)]?)
```

Both options do the same thing. The second is just a little shorter.

This will cause your validator catch any addresses that include @, [@], {@}, |@|, (@).

```
mail@mail.com
mail[@]mail.com
mail{@}mail.com
mail|@|mail.com
mail(@)mail.com
```

You could also try to edit the validator to strip the {}[]|| characters surrounding the @ character in 'value' before you run the match.